# Create NAT64 Networkでデバイスをwifi接続した際に、IPアドレスがIPv4のままです。

Tags: swift, objective-c, iphone, ipv6

来年から必須となるためIPv6の確認をしようとmac OSX 10.11 beta8にて
Create NAT64 Networkの設定にし、wifiでiPhone5S（iOS8.4）を繋げました。

iPhone側の設定>Wi-Fi>で確認したところ
DNSはIPv6になっていましたがIPアドレスはIPv4のままでした。
ちゃんと端末→mac間でIPv6になっているのか疑問です。
これは正常動作なのでしょうか？